# Is there a better way of finding a list of RGB values in pixels with OpenCV rather than looping through a list?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm looking for certain color pixels in a small region of my monitor in a loop that never ends and I'm curious if there is a more efficient approach i could take that would yield the same results if not better.

I thought about using the `inRange` numpy method but i assumed that would lead to me getting false positives as reading the pixels early/late is a problem.

```
import time

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from mss import mss

def main():
    region = {
        "top": 605,
        "left": 1161,
        "width": 240, 
        "height": 240
    }

    pxrgb = [
        [223, 74, 74],
        [219, 63, 63],
        [213, 52, 52],
        [208, 41, 41],
        [202, 30, 30],
        [230, 98, 98],
        [233, 107, 107],
        [235, 115, 115],
        [236, 119, 119],
        [238, 127, 127],
        [240, 135, 135],
        [240, 139, 139],
        [240, 142, 142],
        [241, 147, 147],
        [222, 71, 71],
        [227, 87, 87],
        [229, 93, 93],
        [231, 100, 100],
        [238, 126, 126],
        [226, 87, 87],
        [224, 76, 76],
        [219, 60, 60],
        [239, 135, 135]
    ]

    while True:
        screenshot = np.array(mss().grab(region))
        screenshot = cv.cvtColor(screenshot, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        
        for px in pxrgb:
            result = np.count_nonzero(np.all(screenshot==px, axis=2))
        
            if result != 0:
                print("found pxrgb")
                print(px)
                
                time.sleep(0.1)
                break


if __name__ == "__main__":              
    main()
```

Comment: If performance is an issue, then why explicitly wait between each pixel check? If you want to control the rate at which screenshots are taken, then perhaps you want that sleep in the *outer* loop?

Comment: Notwithstanding what your current code actually does, is the question a) is any one or more of the colours in `pxrgb` on the screen, or b) how many of the colours in `pxrgb` are on the screen? The first question can potentially exit sooner without  requiring an exhaustive check over all the colours, and can be optimised in the long run by putting colours more likely to be present at the top of the list. The second can be optimised by checking all the colours in parallel in a single pass.

Comment: I changed the title from mentioning *"range"* to using *"list"* because a range is normally a contiguous set of numbers with a lower and upper limit including everything in between, whereas OP seems to be seeking a list of discrete, non-adjacent colours. Calling it a *"range"* leads to the idea of using `inRange()` which is not appropriate for a set of discrete colours with gaps between them, IMHO. If OP means something different, my edit can be reversed out.

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially making up to 23 passes over your image, looking for a single, specific colour on each pass. At each pixel, you need to make up to 3 tests in order to know if that pixel matches the colour you are testing. Tests for comparison tend to slow processors down, so one way of reducing the number of tests is to make each RGB triplet into a single 24-bit number as follows:

```
new24BitNumber = Red + 256*Green + 65536*Blue
```

You can do that extremely fast with `np.dot()` like this:

```
sought24 = np.dot(np.array(sought, np.uint32),[1,256,65536])
```

where `sought` is your list of RGB colours you are looking for. You can do this once, up-front before your main processing loop for your list of sought colours and just once inside the loop for your image.

---

Here is some code that shows a way of doing that, with each method encapsulated in a single function call so it can be timed easily using `timeit`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Create dummy 240x240 image of zeroes
im = np.zeros((240,240,3), np.uint8)

# The colours we are seeking
sought = [
        [223, 74, 74],
        [219, 63, 63],
        [213, 52, 52],
        [208, 41, 41],
        [202, 30, 30],
        [230, 98, 98],
        [233, 107, 107],
        [235, 115, 115],
        [236, 119, 119],
        [238, 127, 127],
        [240, 135, 135],
        [240, 139, 139],
        [240, 142, 142],
        [241, 147, 147],
        [222, 71, 71],
        [227, 87, 87],
        [229, 93, 93],
        [231, 100, 100],
        [238, 126, 126],
        [226, 87, 87],
        [224, 76, 76],
        [219, 60, 60],
        [239, 135, 135]
    ]

# Seed a pixel with a colour that we are looking for
# If you use "sought[1]", then "stopOnMatch()" will win
# If you use "sought[2]" or greater, then "usingIsIn()" will win by a large margin
im[0,0,:] = sought[10]

# Make each RGB triplet into a single 24-bit integer: R + 256*G + 65536*B
sought24 = np.dot(np.array(sought, np.uint32),[1,256,65536])

def stopOnMatch():
   """Looks for 'sought' in 'im', stops on first match"""
   for px in sought:
      if np.count_nonzero(np.all(im==px, axis=2)) > 0:
         return 1
   return 0

def counting():
   """Looks for 'sought' in 'im', counting matches"""
   nPresent = 0
   for px in sought:
      nPresent += np.count_nonzero(np.all(im==px, axis=2))
   return nPresent

def usingIsIn():
   """Optimised version of 'counting()' that looks in flattened array"""
   im24 = np.dot(im.astype(np.uint32),[1,256,65536])
   nPresent = np.count_nonzero(np.isin(im24,sought24))
   return nPresent

a = stopOnMatch()
b = counting()
c = usingIsIn()

#%timeit a = stopOnMatch()
#%timeit b = counting()
#%timeit c = usingIsIn()
```

My results show that `usingIsIn()` is around up to 10x faster than the original method:

```
In [63]: %timeit a = stopOnMatch()
8.46 ms ± 6.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [64]: %timeit b = counting()
17.6 ms ± 22.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [65]: %timeit c = usingIsIn()
1.7 ms ± 1.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

It is important to note that the original method will be faster than my method if there is a pixel with one of the first 2 colours in your list. If  only the 11th colour is present, my method will be faster by a factor of 4-5. If none of your list of colours is present, my method will be faster by a factor of 10x.